# How to get the xpath of suggested items of google place auto complete field in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation, google-places-autocomplete, inspection

I am doing a selenium project. There is a field called address which is a google place auto complete field that suggests palces name like dropdown. Problem with the field is,  it cannot be inspected. Whenever i click on inspection button the suggested auto complete list get disappeard?

How can I automate this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? If you use Firefox, you can actually select the items using inspector, but I still get selenium to work with it.